# IIS 7.5 fine tuning

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 on W2k8r2, he is with default configuration. I wonder settings that help improve the performance of IIS and asp.net. This server serves content via webservices. What settings and customizations in IIS and asp.net that consuman use?

Comment: _"Actually, the main problem here is that there can not be “best practices” for a web server. A web server is just a hosting platform for applications, and, each and every application has its own needs. Therefore, in many cases, you will not have one universal best practice"_ [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cenkiscan/archive/2012/06/20/iis-best-practices.aspx)

Comment: What are the points of improvements that I can check?